# How do I implement reselect to derive data for my ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, reselect

I am designing an Angular 2 app with ngrx/store. My state currently looks like

```
export interface State {
    users: Array<User>, 
    polls: Array<Poll>
};

const reducers = {
    users: userReducer.reducer, 
    polls: pollReducer.reducer
}
```

I want a list of all the poll titles from each Poll object. poll_title is a property that exists on each Poll object.

How do I implement createSelector from reselect to get me an array with all of the poll titles?

Comment: Your case is a quite basic one. Did you check `reselect` docs? https://github.com/reactjs/reselect